# What are the format specifiers I can use?

Tags: c, format, specifications

I'm using code::blocks with windows to program in c. Lately, I've hit a few problems trying to find out the addresses and values stored in the addresses of floats, long longs, etc. I've figured out that I need to use "I64d" instead of "lld". Is there a list of the format specifiers that I must use instead of the "normal" ones (e.g. "d", "ld", "lld", etc)? Thanks.

Comment: "argument types"? I get the idea you mean "format specifiers". And: "instead of the 'normal' ones" - what normal ones? It looks like you should have shown code in stead of fuzzy talk.

Comment: @sehe The "normal ones" would be the conversions specified in the standard.

Comment: @sehe, Yes, sorry, I didn't know what they were called, and the first google link said is was that. Corrected.

Comment: @user2377414 I am another "windows-only" guy(unfortunately) who uses Code:blocks for C.But I haven't found any such problems yet.`lld` works fine in my programs.

Comment: @Rüppell's Vulture, Hmm.. which version of Code::Blocks are you using? And which compiler and version of compiler?

Comment: For adresses there should be `%p` and you should cast the pointer to `void*`.

Comment: @user2377414 I use Code::Blocks 10.5. (Changing from TurboC to CodeBlocks was the smartest thing I did while learning C.TurboC screen had made me loathe C/C++)

Answer (score 0):

All the format specifiers are shown in the standard. The current C11 standard shows the "normal ones" in `7.20.6.1 The fprintf function`.

However, there are also the "extra" integer types (such as `uint16_t`) defined in `stdint.h`. The corresponding `fprintf` macros to use as format specifiers for those types are included in `inttypes.h` and detailed in the standard, `7.8.1 Macros for format specifiers`.

An example would be:

```
int16_t val = 42;
printf ("val = %2" PRId16 "\n", val);
```

Keep in mind that there are also equivalents for the `fscanf` side of things as well, with the macros starting with `SCN` instead of `PRI`.